# 2-way Stripe synch with Squarespace , Big Cartel , Woo Commerce etc,

Tags: woocommerce, stripe-payments, squarespace, stripe-connect, bigcartel

I am testing out various eCommerce platforms such as Squarespace , Big Cartel , Woo Commerce etc. I have connected my Stripe account to all of these via Stripe Connect oAuth (Woo via old school copy & paste API key).These are all working correctly and I can make charges from the various eCom platform checkouts which appear both in Stripe and in the eCom platform's Order queue.

I have built a separate, basic Stripe Connect app with read/write access that flags potentially fraudulent Stripe transactions, leaves them in a queue for review, and then can be refunded directly from my app. The refunds initiated from my app are reflected correctly in the Stripe Dashboard.

What I can't seem to figure out is this: How do I make the refunds appear in the eCom apps? Do I need to set up authorization between my app and the eCom platform? How can I refund a charge from my app, which updates Stripe, and subsequently updates the original eCom platform i.e. Squarespace?

Comment: The best solution here would be to flag the transactions but not refund through your app. Instead, go into the correct eCom platform and refund there so that they stay in sync.

Comment: Yes I understand that as the easiest,  low tech , manual alternative. I am looking for a more difficult,  technical solution to be able to update refunds from my app.

Comment: Well, unless each of those platforms decides to listen to webhook events and update their own system when a different application refunds their charges, I'm not sure there's a viable solution here. The only thing I can think of would be to script the refund through each one of those directly but I'm not sure this would be possible.